# MvvmCross custom log provider

Tags: c#, xamarin, logging, mvvmcross

I'm trying to implement my own log provider.

Setup.cs contains:

```cs
protected override MvxLogProviderType GetDefaultLogProviderType() => MvxLogProviderType.None;

protected override IMvxLogProvider CreateLogProvider()
{
    var logger = new Logger();
    return base.CreateLogProvider();
}
```

Logger.cs

```cs
public class Logger : IMvxLog
{
    public bool Log(MvxLogLevel logLevel, Func<string> messageFunc, Exception exception = null, params object[] formatParameters)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var url = new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
        client.PostAsync(url,null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

It crashes with the ViewModel constructor when IoC try to resolve the dependency.

Error message:

> Failed to resolve parameter for parameter log of type IMvxLog when creating
>   eOrder.ViewModel.ActivitiesViewModel

Maybe I don't need to override `MvxLogProviderType.None`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You return the base in `CreateLogProvider()` and since you set the `GetDefaultLogProviderType` to `None`, that will return `null`.

The second problem is that you implement `IMvxLog`, and not `IMvxLogProvider`. Try implementing that one, and return that in the setup instead of the base.

More information can be found at: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/logging#customize-the-log-provider

Not that the custom sample code there is using Serilog, and is accessing the static instance.

```
protected override IMvxLogProvider CreateLogProvider()
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.LiterateConsole()
                .WriteTo.AndroidLog()
                .CreateLogger();
    return base.CreateLogProvider();
}
```